# Camera movement in unity engine

Tags: camera, unity, mouse, scrolling

I have a basic camera setup which is angled like so:

```
x: 30
y: 0 
z: 0
Projection: Orthographic
```

And i attached a C# component to it and made it so the camera moves with a right click and drag movement.

The problem is its not moving at the same amount as the mouse. I had to set a value for scroll speed to 1000 and even then its still too slow.

I want the camera to move with the mouse in a more raw amount, then i wish to add some lerp effect to it so it feels a bit more slick.

I don't know why the movement is so slow, i come from a 2D background and am learning 3D so i suspect my lack of understanding of 3D positions might be the issue.

This is my current code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class cameraMove : MonoBehaviour {


// VARIABLES
public float panSpeed = 1000.0f;

private Vector3 mouseOrigin;
private bool isPanning;


void Start ()
{
    Vector3 pos = GameObject.Find("Sun").transform.position;
    Camera.main.transform.LookAt (pos);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{


    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (1)) 
    {
        //right click was pressed   
        mouseOrigin = Input.mousePosition;
        isPanning = true;
    }


    // cancel on button release
    if (!Input.GetMouseButton (1)) 
    {
        isPanning = false;
    }

    //move camera on X & Y
    if (isPanning) 
    {
        Vector3 pos     = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint (mouseOrigin-Input.mousePosition);

        // update x and y but not z
        Vector3 move    = new Vector3 (pos.x * panSpeed, pos.y * panSpeed, 0);

        Camera.main.transform.Translate (move, Space.World);
        mouseOrigin = Input.mousePosition;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You code should work fine, in fact 1000 will get you to the north pole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Input.GetAxisRaw](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxisRaw.html) might be what you're looking for. In the Input Manager (Edit -> Project Settings -> Input) setup a variable for "Mouse X" and "Mouse Y" (if not already setup [as below]).

[image]

Then in code;

```
public class CameraMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector2 pos;
    private bool    isPanning;

    public void Start()
    {
        pos = new Vector2();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
            isPanning = true;

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1))
            isPanning = false;

        if (isPanning)
        {
            pos.Set(Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X"), -Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y"));
            transform.Translate(pos, Space.World);
        }
    }
}
```

For movement in the Y plane, the value from the mouse must be negated to, unless you with to use inverted controls. Hope this helped.

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion i tried this method doing this: http://pastebin.com/9CRhWag8

But it doesn't quite work, the camera just jitters in the same spot, but not actually scroll. What might i have gotten wrong?

Comment: Updated my answer for code example, you were very close; you didn't need to save the origin of the mouse, as GetAxisRaw returns the current movement of the mouse for that frame. I also swapped !InputGetButton(1) for Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1), (the functionality you were looking for). Hope this solves your problem, let me know if you need any more help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can compare `Input.mousePosition` (in pixels) directly:

```
static Vector3 mouseDelta;
//from (-Screen.width, -Screen.height, 0) to (Screen.width, Screen.height, 0)
mouseDelta = (mouseOrigin - Input.mousePosition);
//convert pixels to world-units
mouseDelta /= panSpeed;
Camera.main.transform.Translate(mouseDelta, Space.World);
mouseOrigin = Input.mousePosition;
```

Note: you should clamp the transform's position to valid coordinates.

Comment: Why do i need to divide by panSpeed? I want to be able to move the camera without the need for a variable so it will move with my mouse in a 1 to 1 way.

Comment: @wduk, you don't have to; 1:1 is ok if it works for you. I think the problem is `ScreenToViewportPoint`.

Comment: I will check it out after work to see if I can get it working and will let you know.